# Looking for public source for time series data: DAX/DE40

Tags: finance, historical, time-series

The Deutsche Bundesbank (the German central bank) provides publicly available statistical data at https://www.bundesbank.de/en/statistics/time-series-databases

This includes a number of time series related to capital markets, financial markets and general macroeconomic time series.

Up until November 2023, these time series included time series for the DAX, a German stock market index. This time series was available using the identifier "BBK01.WU3141". In November 2023, the Bundesbank changed their nomenclature and apparently also changed the series which were made available. I cannot find this time series at their page anymore.

Does anyone have either a suggestion where to find the "new" identifier and time series, if existent, or another publicly available source with downloadable time series data? I'm not looking for real-time values, only historical data for research purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can download daily open, high, low and close data [here from Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGDAXI/history/) for the DAX Performance Index.

Alternatively, you can [click on "Data" at the bottom of this page](https://www.dax-indices.com/index-details?isin=DE0008469008), which is, [by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAX) the official homepage of the DAX (a claim I am not qualified to evaluate - depending on how "serious" your application is, you may want to dig deeper. But if you are doing "serious" analyses, then I assume you would not be asking here, no?)